# Sphinx Search mysql client on production server

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx, production, mysql

I want to connect to SphinxQL on my production server to execute sphinx queries on mysql database,

**Please note I ran the following commands in the production server terminal(Ubuntu 10.04) by connecting to it remotely.**

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 9312

mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 9306

mysql -h <<my_production_ip_address>> -P 9312

mysql -h <<my_production_ip_address>> -P 9306
```

**Tried changing the bind_address in /etc/mysql/my.cnf to my_production_ip_address.**

I want to run a sphinx query on my production server for debugging.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure you have the following line in sphinx configuration file (usually sphinx.conf) under searchd {...} section:

```
listen = 9306:mysql41
```

if not, then please add it and restart Sphinx.

Please also make sure that:

1. Sphinx daemon (searchd) is up and running
2. Sphinx is listening port 9306 (run netstat -anp | grep LIST )
3. Firewall is configured to pass network connection to port 9306 (it usually does)

Hope this helps.

Comment: It worked, thanks!. I would love to listen to why its required?

Comment: Sphinx supports two different protocols: binary API and SphinxQL. For compatibility with old versions by default Sphinx is serving API calls (and also master-agent Sphinx connection for distributed indexes) so you have to make it listen on the separate port to serve SphinxQL queries. I have no idea why it requires two different ports, but I expect it's because of compatibility with mysql clients.