# sphinx connection error in php

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

After a lot of tries and research i have successfully index the sphinx search, installed foolz package with the composer using putty but when I am trying to search in my php file it give me error "`Warning: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /var/www/html/vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/Connection.php on line 176`" below is the code that I am using for search.

```
require "vendor/autoload.php";
use Foolz\SphinxQL\SphinxQL;
use Foolz\SphinxQL\Connection;

$conn = new Connection();
$conn->setParams(array('host' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => 3312));

$query = SphinxQL::create($conn)->select('column_one', 'colume_two')
    ->from('index_ancient', 'index_main', 'index_delta')
    ->match('comment', 'my opinion is superior to yours')
    ->where('banned', '=', 1);

$result = $query->execute();
```

and I am unable to find my next step. this is the link that I am referring currently, `http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2014/10/20/sphinxql-query-builder-for-php/`.
Please help

Comment: Is sphinx service running local?

Comment: no it's running on my VPS

Comment: The service should be running on the VPS because you are defining the connection to point to the running machine

Comment: Yes, Currently it is running on VPS from Linode. I would appreciate if you can let me know if there are any other points you can help with!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should fix sphinx.conf like this question: [Sphinx Search mysql client on production server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374558/sphinx-search-mysql-client-on-production-server)

Add listening by mysql client:

```
listen = 9306:mysql41
```

Comment: Thnx for your answer, but my issue is resolve as the thing that I was missing is restart the searchd after chagne the port and host in the conf file.